# Send data to DynamoDb over intermittent connection

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have an application that needs to send data to a cloud database (DynamoDb).

The app runs on a computer that can lose internet connectivity or be switched off at any time, but I must ensure that all data eventually gets to the cloud database.
I can assume the application will eventually be switched on, and will eventually get internet access back.

The app is written in VB .NET

What are some schemes for achieving this, and are there any ready-made products that already achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a write-through cache using a local DynamoDB instance (or even using SQLite).  But without getting specific details about what kind of data you'd be storing into the database, and what data should be made available "offline" it's hard to say exactly how you should structure your application. You'll definitely want to not keep everything local, unless the volume of data is really small overall.

Then there is the problem of resolving conflicts that may occur during network partitions (ie. a client goes offline and makes some database modifications, while other clients also make modifications to the database; these need to be reconciled and it's up to you, and your users to determine how)

It's not a simple problem to solve.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I was afraid someone would say this.
I'm fortunate enough that my offline data structure is simple and only need one-way replication (app to cloud).
I will look into developing something that will run periodically on the local machine and push the updates to the cloud db.

Comment: Hi @timyha, even if you are only doing one-way replication, unless there is no possibility of conflict the problem is still non-trivial; however, if no conflicts are possible then all you have to do is write the data to a local store first, and then fire off a background thread to write to dynamo (and remove entries as they are written)